# hook_menu title callback on wildcard

Tags: routes

I have two pages, the first page 'test' has links to test/%.
On test/% I want to have different titles but some how this wildcard
and the title callback aren't working properly.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function cjgimport_menu() {
  $items['test'] = array(
    'title' => t('Test title'),
    'title callback' => 'function_title_callback',
    'title arguments' => array(0),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page callback' => 'function_content_callback',
  );

  $items['test/%'] = array(
    'title' => t('Test title'),
    'title callback' => 'function_title_callback',
    'title arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page callback' => 'function_content_callback',
  );

  return $items;
);

/**
 * Custom callback function for title
 */
function function_title_callback($arg) {
  if($arg == 0) {
    $title = ucfirst(arg(0));
  } else {
    $title = ucfirst(arg(1));
  }
  return $title;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the title doesn't work on the test/% pages?

Comment: If you `dpm($arg)`, do you see what you expect to see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide the wildcard as `title arguments`:

```
$items['test/%'] = array(
  'title' => t('Test title'),
  'title callback' => 'function_title_callback',
  'title arguments' => array(1),
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'page callback' => 'function_content_callback',
);
```

And obviously make sure that your function is actually called `function_title_callback()` (which you've listed in `hook_menu()`), and not `cjgimport_title_callback()`, which you have listed in the question.

You should also be using the `$arg` variable, not the `arg()` function in your callback...but I guess that might be the result of debugging.

Comment: Yes sorry, was making that as 'test' code. Forgot to change the function. I added the title arguments as array(1).

The function_title_callback($arg) does not seem to work though.

Comment: Did you clear the cache after changing hook_menu()? It needs to be done every time as routes are cached

Comment: @Erikdekamps can you make your question match your comment, then? Or ask another question? And "does not seem to work" is very, very vague. Expected and encountered behaviour would be better ;) And if it's not, in fact, cache, can you simplify your callback, get rid of `ucfirst` and possibly `switch` - so we could know if the callback is called at all, and what's in it's `$arg`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I will change the part where it says $arg. The 'title arguments' => array(1) does pass through the $arg and works but in the $items['test/%/'] I would expect it to pass through the second argument.

Comment: Oh. You need to `return $items` from `hook_menu()` obviously ;)

Comment: Sorry Clive, I forgot to add that here as well, I did return them. The question was solved by a collegue by overriding the title in the view contextual filter.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember to put the loader function in the same file where your menu function is in, it usually is the .module file. In my case, my loader function wouldnt fire when i put it in the .inc file.